# Cannot edit the properties of an empty Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a C# .NET Framework Console Application Project in a freshly installed Visual Studio 2019 Community.

In Solution Explorer, after right-clicking `ConsoleApp1` → `Properites`, a window appears, but instead of having the Project settings, it only contains the following error:

```
An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: val
```

Unfortunately, I have zero idea how to approach this problem. I attempted recreating the solution, yet this problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

​I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2019 for Windows. I was able to resolve it by installing Universal Windows Platform (UWP).